# Clean Spray Foam off Gold Ring

Tags: spray-foam

So, I wasn’t thinking the other day installing a door, and I got spray foam expanding insulation all over my hands (which are fine, it’s coming off), but also on my gold wedding band.

I’m not sure what the best way to clean the ring is. Any advice?

The foam is “GE Insulating Foam Gaps and Cracks”.

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed, it's not a duplicate. The linked question deals with metal construction, not gold jewelry. The answer given would not have fixed the problem like the selected answer in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's real gold, the usual suspects should work—something like Goof Off, or probably even plain acetone.

Comment: The acetone worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One can buy gun cleaner, or in aerosol can form, from the same place the expanding foam was bought. For a smaller price, acetone (nail varnish remover) works as well.

Buying acetone in very small quantities works out expensive  per volume. I tend to buy 5 litres, in a plastic container, as it's a good solvent for many other things, too. And gold won't melt before your very eyes!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you can get the ring off your finger.  If not this will still work.

Allow the foam to harden. Scrape as much as you can off with your fingernail or something plastic.
I have used WD-40 and a soft cloth, with lots of rubbing and polishing.
There are more caustic chemicals that will break the foam down, but the WD-40 is less damaging to skin.
A final wash with soap and water, and I had a new looking ring.

Good Luck